# How to get Lists of beans in action from JSP?

Tags: java, struts2, arraylist, javabeans

I am using Struts 2 and Eclipse to create an application.

I have a bean class for Currency Exchange Rate (with properties "currency", "description", "rate").

I get a list of data using a DAO and show it in JSP using `<s:iterator>`.

But I add "New Rate" text box at every row to "Update" currency rate. I want to update it all at the same time if textbox has value. How do I get lists of beans from my JSP to my action class?

Comment: Please show us some code, so we can start from there

Comment: you question is still not clear.can you try to rephrase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to send a map instead of a list.

The iteration would create a textfield for each bean using [map-based field names](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-AnadvancedexampleforindexedListsandMaps), likely keyed by the currency conversion bean's ID.

The processing action would re-persist the beans using the new values, already converted by Struts 2, in the action's map of beans.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to send an HTTP request to the server.  You can  do this using Javascript (AJAX) or a basic HTML form.  The request would contain the contents of the text boxes and would be sent to a Java servlet on the server (or whatever Struts uses).  Then, using the data that was sent in the request, the servlet would update the Java bean.